# Linear Mixed Models or Structural Equation Modeling, which one to use?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, glmm

I am currently trying to figure out whether to use LMM or SEM (or something else?) for my longitudinal mediation study (3 time points). I want to investigate the effects mentioned below, and I am wondering whether this would be possible with LMM, especially because the DV at previous time influences MED at next time point. IV are interventions, MED measured construct with survey, DV is behavior. I am not necessarily interested in latent variables.

I could use SPSS, Python or R ...

**Direct effects and mediation:**

IV1 (t2)       -> MED (t2) -> DV (t2)

IV2 (t1)       -> MED (t2) -> DV (t2)                    (lagged direct)

IV1 (t2) * IV2 -> MED (t2) -> DV (t2)                    (lagged interaction)

IV1 (t3)       -> MED (t3) -> DV (t3)

IV2 (t1)       -> MED (t3) -> DV (t3)                    (lagged direct)

IV1 (t3) * IV2 -> MED (t3) -> DV (t3)                    (lagged interaction)

**Effect on subsequent period (autoregressive effects)**

MED t1 - > MED t2  ->  MED t3

DV t1  -> DV t2    -> DV t3

**Changes:**

MED t2 – t1

MED t3 – t1

DV t2 – t1

DV t3 – t1

**Time-varying confounders:**

DV t1 -> MED t2

DV t2 -> MED t3

▲ DV t2 – t1  -> MED t3